# How to prevent IDA Pro from loading DWARF debug info in batch mode?

Tags: mach-o, ida

I'm trying to evaluate a Mach-O object file by running `idal -b <mach.o>` from within another program and working with the .idb produced. But I'm having troubles with this.

By running idaq a few times and toggling some options, I've found that the issue is with the 'Load DWARF debug information' option. If I select yes, the disassembly is poor - it's almost all considered data. If I select no, the disassembly looks as I'd expect.

The result from `idal -b <mach.o>` looks like the result where the DWARF debug information has been loaded.

So I'm looking for a way to toggle off the loading of the DWARF info programatically. Is there a command-line option or something I can put in a config file somewhere when I'm evaluating a Mach-O file? I would like the behavior to remain as-is if I'm evaluating an ELF object file, so I don't want to use the 'don't ask me again' option in the GUI prompt.

I'm running IDA Pro 6.5 on Ubuntu 14.